# How to print certain pages based on a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that has 3 worksheets and I have placed page breaks on the first worksheet to make the document look better.  The first worksheet is 6 pages long.  I would only like to print pages based on the value in cell E54.  If "E54"=0 then print pages 1, 5 and 6. If "E54" is greater than 0 and less than 8 then print pages 1, 2, 5 and 6. If "E54" is greater than 7 and less than 15 then print pages 1, 2, 3, 5 and 6. If "E54" is greater than 14 then print all pages.

Here is the Macro that I am currently using to print all worksheets.

```
Sub Print_All_Pages()
'
' Run Macros to hide blank rows then print all three worksheets
'
Sheet2.Hide_Blank_Rows2
Sheet3.Hide_Blank_Rows3
'
    Sheets(Array("Inspection Report", "Device List", "Deficiencies")).Select
    Sheets("Inspection Report").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False


End Sub
```

Because I am hiding rows based on the value of cell "E54" it is still printing the pages with just the rows that are repeated at the top of every page.

Comment: So do a `case` statement on `E54` and set `Copies:=variable`. Edit: oops, not copies. Print area XD

Comment: google search for sheets printout gets ... [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838253.aspx) . Use `from` and `to` to specify the page range you want to print.

Comment: Thanks for giving me some direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to write the code but it works.

```
Sub Print_Pages()

Sheet2.Hide_Blank_Rows2
Sheet3.Hide_Blank_Rows3

Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inspection Report")

    Select Case CStr(Sheet.Range("E54").Value2)
    Case "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"

' Print_Pages_1_2_5_6

    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=2, Copies:=1, Collate _
        :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=5, To:=6, Copies:=1, Collate _
        :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    Sheets(Array("Device List", "Deficiencies")).Select
    Sheets("Device List").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False

    Case "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"

' Print_Pages_1_2_3_5_6

    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=3, Copies:=1, Collate _
        :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=5, To:=6, Copies:=1, Collate _
        :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    Sheets(Array("Device List", "Deficiencies")).Select
    Sheets("Device List").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False

    Case "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"

' Print_Pages_1_2_3_4_5_6 Macro

    Sheets(Array("Inspection Report", "Device List", "Deficiencies")).Select
    Sheets("Inspection Report").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False

    Case Else
        ' none
    End Select

End Sub
```